# SQL Count returns wrong result

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

My SQL query:

```
              SELECT
                TO_CHAR(se2.ID) S_ID,
                TO_CHAR(se2.file_name) S_NAME,
                TO_CHAR(pl.pid) P_ID,
                count (*) COUNTER
              FROM
                pl
              join po on po.id = pl.po_id 
              join ppl on po.fk_product_id = ppl.fk_product
              join se on se.id = po.fk_product_id
              join  se2 on se2.id = ppl.fk_parent
              WHERE 
                pl.project_id = 227739470
              GROUP BY se2.ID, se2.file_name, pl.pid
```

Returns me 16 rows, but count(*) is 1 in every result row!
I want to get the amount of all rows in every result line.
Whats the problem here?

Comment: what should it be? If each of the 16 rows occurs only once, that would be correct.

Comment: Then I've some logic problem. I want the amount of all rows in every result -> '16' in every result row...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want every row to have a column with the total number of rows in it, then use:

```
count(*) over () total_rows
```

You do not need to use a group by as this is an analytic function, not an aggregate function.